# Phonograph : How to filter data?

Tags: filter, palantir-foundry, foundry-phonograph

This is my query in Palantir to get my data using Phonograph

```
{
"extractors": {
    "result": "$"
},
"headers": {},
"method": "POST",
"path": "search/tables",
"pathParams": {},
"queryParams": {},
"bodyJson": {
    "tableRids": [
        "mytablerid"
    ],
    "filter": {
        "type": "and",
        "and": [
            {
                "type": "queryString",
                "queryString": {
                    "queryString": "status:('OK')"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It works I get my data with OK status

And now I have another request, how can I use this query string to get all my data (all status ?)

I tried this :

```
{
"extractors": {
    "result": "$"
},
"headers": {},
"method": "POST",
"path": "search/tables",
"pathParams": {},
"queryParams": {},
"bodyJson": {
    "tableRids": [
        "mytablerid"
    ],
    "filter": {
        "type": "and",
        "and": [
            {
                "type": "queryString",
                "queryString": {
                    "queryString": "status:('')"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But it return no data ...

Thanks in advance for helping !

Answer (score 0):

To get all data from a search query you can use the `matchAll` filter. Here's the relevant documentation:
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/references-writeback/#selecting-rows